# Is there a conflict between [temp.spec]/5 and [basic.odr] w.r.t. the odr-rule for explicit specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization, one-definition-rule

#### Background

There are several Q&As that cover the fact that an explicit specialization of, say, a function template, is not a function template but a function, and thus falls under [[basic.def.odr]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#13.3)

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] inline function or variable

such that the following example is (frequently) shown as well-formed:

```
// foo.h
// -----
template<typename T>
void foo(T) {}

// explicit specialization
template<>
inline void foo<int>(int) { int a; (void)a; }
// ^^^ note: inline

// bar.cpp
----------
#include "foo.h"

void bar() { foo<int>(42); }

// baz.cpp
----------
#include "foo.h"

void baz() { foo<int>(42); }
```

specifically, as per [basic.def.odr]/13.3, there is no odr-violation even if `foo<int>(int)` is defined in both translation units (the TUs relating to `bar.cpp` and `baz.cpp`), as the explicit specialization/the function is `inline`.

However, according to [[temp.spec]/5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#5.2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> For a given template and a given set of template-arguments, [...] **an explicit specialization shall be defined at most once in a program** (according to [basic.def.odr]),

an explicit specialization shall be defined at most once in a program (albeit with a reference to [basic.def.odr]; no particular section).

#### Question

- Is there a conflict between [temp.spec]/5 and [basic.odr] w.r.t. the odr-rule for explicit specializations? Or should the rule of the former simply be read as "except for where [[basic.def.odr]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#13.3) applies"?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14.sentence-3

Comment: @cpplearner how does this paragraph apply to explicit specializations?

Comment: @cpplearner But `D` is arguably neither a template nor a templated entity here, its an explicit specialization of one; would /14 still apply?

Comment: IIUC The sentence applies to every entity listed in [basic.def.odr]/13.

Comment: @cpplearner IIUC «For each such entity» refers to «These requirements also apply to corresponding entities defined within each definition of `D`», where «[If] `D` is a template ...»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think "If D is a template" is local to the first sentence of p14, and `D` in subsequent sentences refers to "such an entity `D`" introduced in [p13](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13.sentence-2). Consider opening an editorial issue if you think this is not clear enough.

Comment: @cpplearner For me it is clear enough that if the paragraph starts with «If `D` is a template...», the rest of the paragraph by `D` means that template, not something else from the previous paragraph.

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4498 .